# Screensaver with DreamService

Tags: android, screensaver, dreamservice

I'm trying to make a simple screensaver which display pictures with DreamService but I allways got a simple colors screensaver.

there is my code:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alex.testdreamservice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name=".ScreenSaver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="Picture ScreenSaver">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

#### ScreenSaver.java

```
public class ScreenSaver extends DreamService {
    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
        setFullscreen(true);
        setScreenBright(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.screensaver_layout);
        findViewById(R.id.image_view).setBackground(getDrawableFromAsset("picture.jpeg"));
    }

    private Drawable getDrawableFromAsset(String url) {
        try {
            return Drawable.createFromStream(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(url), null);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### screensaver_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Hello World !"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone finds a mistake, please let me know.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE"`:

```
<service
        android:name=".ScreenSaver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Picture ScreenSaver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```